# Определение относительного пути в fs

Tags: node.js

Есть файл index.js, папка lib с файлом lib.js и папка data с файлом data.json
index.js содержит строку
`let lib = require('./lib/lib.js')`
lib.js экспортит функцию и содержит внутри нее строку
`fs.readFileSync('./data/data.json')`
на разных устройствах при одинаковой версии node js index.js читает то
`./data/data.json`, как и предполагается, то
`./lib/data/data.json`

от чего это зависит?

Comment: Задайте вопрос корректнее, что _в итоге_ должно быть и какая структура папок в данный момент имеется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956316/how-to-set-working-directory-for-node-js-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от того, из какой папки вы запустили ноду. Существует такое понятие, как текущая директория - именно ее и считает `fs` за `.`, как и в любых других языках программирования.

Comment: он считает за текущую директорию расположение именно запускаемого файла или запрашиваемого?

Comment: @Loskir текущая директория привязывается к процессу, а не к файлу.

Comment: а откуда стартует процесс?

Comment: @Loskir оттуда, откуда вы его запускаете

Comment: но в моей ситуации как будто процесс стартует то из ./, то из ./lib/

Comment: @Loskir значит, так запускаете